# An algorithm to find a path (schedule classes)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-traversal

I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem..it is taken from a programming competition held for grade 12 students. 
The task is to have the student 'Karli' take enough classes to obtain 214 credits. The student can't take more or less than 214 credits before entering the exam room. The doors are represented in the diagram. The user may repeat a class for additional classes, but they must leave that classroom..go to another classroom..and then come back.

I tried to do this manually and was able to find one solution with path:

Math-algebra-philosophy-algebra-math-modeling-calculus-modeling-exam

I am trying to develop an algorithm that will find a path given the number of credits required (i.e 214 for this case)

here is what I've tried and gotten stuck on :

Representing the map as a graph with the door being a double edge between the two nodes. However I don't know what graph traversal algorithm will allow me to solve this problem?

Would converting the graph to an adjacency matrix make things any easier?

Thanks

Comment: Can Karli leave the math room from the bottom door and enter the exam room from the left door?

Comment: No. the bottom math room is entrance only and the left exam room is exit only. The only way to enter the exam room is through modeling room

Comment: Does Kerli have to take the class in the room which he enters?

Comment: Yes. Everytime he enters a room it assumes that the class has been taken and he earns the credits. So no matter what he will start with the math class and earn 17 credits and end with modeling class and earn 29 credits

Comment: @user1411893 Wanted to add a better description to the two solutions below. Both of them appear to be backtracking algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking. The idea is essentially a brute force. Start in the math room, try some other room. Keep trying until you fail, then undo a class and try something else. Intuitively the brute force will get you all answers (if any), but it generally isn't very performant if the graph becomes large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Breadth First Search` will solve this problem.

Record the status `(room, credit)` when Karli arrived at room numbered as `room` with a credit value recorded in `credit`.

Using a `queue` to maintain the data. At the beginning, only (outside, 0) is in the queue. Each time, pop the head, and move from the status described by `head` to each neighbour room of `head`, then calculate the new status and push them into the end of the `queue`(remember to use a hash to avoid a same status being added more than once).

When you reach a status `(exam, 214)`, the expand process finishes. The remaining work is to traverse back from the status `(exam, 214)`. When getting a new status in BFS, you can also record the pointer to precursor status.

Here is my code.

```
char name[][15] = {
        "exam",
        "stochastic",
        "modeling",
        "calculus",
        "math",
        "modern arts",
        "algebra",
        "philosophy",
        "outside"
};

int credits[]={0, 23, 29, 20, 17, 17, 35, 32, 0};

int neighbour[][7]={
        { 1, 2, -1},
        { 2, 3, -1},
        { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, -1},
        { 1, 2, 4,-1},
        { 2, 3, 6, -1},
        { 2, 6, 7, -1},
        { 4, 5, 7, -1},
        { 5, 6, -1},
        { 4, -1}
};


class Node{
public:
        int pos;
        int credit;
        bool operator <( const Node a) const{
                return pos < a.pos || pos == a.pos && credit < a.credit;
        }
};

vector<Node> Q;
vector<int> pred;
set<Node> hash;
void bfs(){
        int n = 9;
        bool found = false;
        hash.clear();
    Node start;
        start.pos = 8, start.credit = 0;
        Q.push_back(start);
        pred.push_back(-1);
        hash.insert(start);
        for(int f=0; f<Q.size(); ++f){
                Node head = Q[f];
                int pos = head.pos;
                //printf("%d %d -> \n", head.pos, head.credit);
                for(int i=0; neighbour[pos][i]!=-1; ++i){
                        Node tmp;
                        tmp.pos = neighbour[pos][i];
                        tmp.credit = head.credit + credits[tmp.pos];
                        if(tmp.credit > 214) continue;
                        if(hash.count(tmp)) continue;
                        if(tmp.credit !=214 && tmp.pos==0)continue;   // if the credit is not 214, then it is not allowed to enter exame room(numbered as 0)
                        Q.push_back(tmp);
                        pred.push_back(f);
                        //printf("    -> %d, %d\n", tmp.pos, tmp.credit);
                        if(tmp.credit==214 && tmp.pos==0){
                                found = true;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                if(found)break;
        }
        stack<int> ss;
        int idx = Q.size()-1;
        while(true){
                ss.push(Q[idx].pos);
                if(pred[idx]!=-1) idx=pred[idx];
                else break;
        }
        for(int credit=0; ss.size() > 0; ){
                int pos = ss.top();
                credit += credits[pos];
                printf("%s(%d) ", name[pos], credit);
                ss.pop();
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

UPD1: Sorry I make some mistakes when assigning values to `neighbour[]`. I hava corrected it.

UPD1: Sorry I forget to check whether credit is 214 when enter the exam room. I hava corrected it.

UPD3: @Nuclearman says that it does not give all the solutions. We only need to remove `hash` from the code, and calculate the path when generating a new status with credit 214. I give the new code here.

```
char name[][15] = {
        "exam",
        "stochastic",
        "modeling",
        "calculus",
        "math",
        "modern arts",
        "algebra",
        "philosophy",
        "outside"
};

int credits[]={0, 23, 29, 20, 17, 17, 35, 32, 0};

int neighbour[][7]={
        { 1, 2, -1},
        { 2, 3, -1},
        { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, -1},
        { 1, 2, 4,-1},
        { 2, 3, 6, -1},
        { 2, 6, 7, -1},
        { 4, 5, 7, -1},
        { 5, 6, -1},
        { 4, -1}
};


class Node{
public:
        int pos;
        int credit;
        bool operator <( const Node a) const{
                return pos < a.pos || pos == a.pos && credit < a.credit;
        }
};

vector<Node> Q;
vector<int> pred;
set<Node> hash;

void outputpath(){
        stack<int> ss;
        int idx = Q.size()-1;
        while(true){
                ss.push(Q[idx].pos);
                if(pred[idx]!=-1) idx=pred[idx];
                else break;
        }
        for(int credit=0; ss.size() > 0; ){
                int pos = ss.top();
                credit += credits[pos];
                printf("%s(%d) ", name[pos], credit);
                ss.pop();
        }
        printf("\n");
}

void bfs(){
        int n = 9;
        bool found = false;
        hash.clear();
        Node start;
        start.pos = 8, start.credit = 0;
        Q.push_back(start);
        pred.push_back(-1);
        hash.insert(start);
        for(int f=0; f<Q.size(); ++f){
                Node head = Q[f];
                int pos = head.pos;
                for(int i=0; neighbour[pos][i]!=-1; ++i){
                        Node tmp;
                        tmp.pos = neighbour[pos][i];
                        tmp.credit = head.credit + credits[tmp.pos];
                        if(tmp.credit > 214) continue;
                        if(hash.count(tmp)) continue;
                        if(tmp.credit !=214 && tmp.pos==0)continue;
                        Q.push_back(tmp);
                        pred.push_back(f);
                        if(tmp.credit==214 && tmp.pos==0){
                                outputpath();
                                /* uncomment the next line to get only one solution*/
                                //found = true;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                if(found)break;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking this won't provide all solutions since a class may be taken multiple times, which isn't allowed in BFS.

Comment: @Nuclearman The author @user1411893 seems only need one solution. But if you really need all the solutions, you can give up the `hash` and only check whether the credit is not beyond 214 so that all possible solutions can be visited as the queue grows. What's more, `"a class may be taken multiple times, which isn't allowed in BFS"` is not properly, which depends on how you control enqueue operations.

Comment: @Nuclearman Indeed my solution already allows a class taken multiple times. `outside(0)`->`math(17)`->`algebra(52)`->`modern arts(69)`->`philosophy(101)`->`algebra(136)`->`philosophy(168)`->`modern arts(185)`->`modeling(214)`->`exam(214)`.

Comment: If that was already in your code, then my apologies for missing that it was possible.

Comment: Kun Huang thanks!
Just one question what is the this suppose to do? :

        bool operator <( const Node a) const{
                return pos < a.pos || pos == a.pos && credit < a.credit;
        }

I am trying to write this in java

Comment: @user1411893 It defines give the order between two objects of `Node`, or `comparator` function of the class `Node`, which is neccessary for using `set`. In Java, you can use `HashMap` or `HashSet` instead. They also require a `Comparator` class.

Comment: what about pred? what are you using that for

Comment: @user1411893 `pred[i]` records the index of `Node`'s predecessor in `Q`. In another words, 'Q[i]` is generated from `Q[pred[i]]`. `pred[i]` is used to find the path.

Comment: Isn't Q a queue? why would you need to keep track of the predecessor? Wouldn't popping each item from the queue give you the path in reverse? (which you add to a stack to represent the path)

Comment: @user1411893 There are many extra nodes stored in the queue. Keeping track of predecessors will be more efficient. I use the stack for the reason that my code traces the path back from the `exam` room to the start but we need to output it from start to `exam` room. `stack` can be omitted if BFS from `exam` room to the start.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version in Haskell, generating paths backwards from the exam room and discarding paths with credit sums greater than the requirement:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Control.Monad (guard)

classes = [("exam",["modeling"])
          ,("modeling",["exam","stochastic","calculus","math","modern arts"])
          ,("stochastic",["calculus","modeling"])
          ,("calculus",["stochastic","modeling","math"])
          ,("math",["calculus","modeling","algebra"])
          ,("algebra",["math","philosophy"])
          ,("philosophy",["algebra","modern arts"])
          ,("modern arts",["philosophy","modeling"])]

credits = [("exam",0)
          ,("modeling",29)
          ,("stochastic",23)
          ,("calculus",20)
          ,("math",17)
          ,("algebra",35)
          ,("philosophy",32)
          ,("modern arts",17)]

solve requirement = solve' ["exam"] 0 where
  solve' path creditsSoFar =
    if creditsSoFar == requirement && head path == "math"
       then [path]
       else do
         next <- fromJust (lookup (head path) classes)
         guard (next /= "exam" 
                && creditsSoFar + fromJust (lookup next credits) <= requirement)
         solve' (next:path) (creditsSoFar + fromJust (lookup next credits))
```

Output:

```
*Main> solve 214
[["math","algebra","philosophy","algebra","math","modeling","calculus","modeling","exam"]
,["math","calculus","math","calculus","math","calculus","math","calculus","math","calculus","modeling","exam"]
,["math","algebra","philosophy","modern arts","philosophy","algebra","math","modeling","exam"]]
(0.19 secs, 9106396 bytes)
```